# How to update Excel records after 'Merge' using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Everyone, I have some problems for to leaning program by myself

1. I have two different excel for compare...

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCkEo.png)
2. Below is my expected result after compare and update Data2.xlsx...

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RGLC.png)
3. But i have no idea how to make my expected result, please can anyone teach me?

   ```
    import pandas as pd 
    dt1 = pd.read_excel('Data1.xlsx')
    dt2 = pd.read_excel('Data2.xlsx')
    df_merge = pd.merge(dt1.iloc[:, [0, 1]], dt2.iloc[:, [0, 2]], on=['Name', 'Reg Date'], how='outer', indicator=True)
    for a in df_merge.iloc[:, [2]].values:
        if a == 'both':
   ```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```py
import pandas as pd 
dt1 = pd.read_excel('Data1.xlsx')
dt2 = pd.read_excel('Data2.xlsx')

dt1['Data1.xlsx'] = 'Y'
df_merge = dt2.merge(dt1, how='left', on=['Name', 'Reg Date'])
df_merge['Data1.xlsx'] = df_merge['Data1.xlsx'].fillna('N')
```

Comment: Can you mark my answer as accepted if you are satisfied with the result?